# List of all errors in project in CLion

Tags: ide, clion

CLion 2016.2 helpfully detects potential errors in the file you're editing, which can be seen in the validation bar to the right of the code.

That's just a single file though, is there a way (like a tool window) to get a list of all such warnings in the whole project, or specific parts of it?

Bonus points if it also lists warnings and errors from the compiler, though that's less important, because the compiler output already includes any it found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The feature you are looking for is called the *Inspector*.

Do: `Find Action... | Inspect Code`. It will show a pop-up that will allow you to select the scope: file, whole project, custom, and the *Inspection profile* (you can choose the type of errors you want to see):

[image]

After clicking OK, this is an example of the output, that you can navigate with the mouse or with keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For beginners reading this: `Find Action...` can be invoked by double-tapping `Shift`.

Answer (score 2):

In version 2017.2, I have it under `Code | Inspect Code...`.

You can also right click a folder in `Project` view and select `Inspect Code...` there to be able to check only that folder.