# How to view build issues in Clion more readable?

Tags: build, qt-creator, clion, readable

In QT Creator build issues are showed in window as readable, filterable, customizable list.

Example of build issues in Qt Creator:

[image]

But in CLion it just a text list with links to build issues.

Example of build issues in CLion:

[image]

How to view build issues in CLion more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main reason is that Qt Creator uses the clang toolkit to gather semantic information about the code, while CLion has its own C++ parser. As such, CLion has a direct representation of the compiler errors and warnings, as you mention.

On the other hand, CLion is able to notify you of errors and warnings without compiling the code, immediately :-) This feature is called "Code inspection", is customizable and filterable, and will give you even more information than the compiler.

You can find it under `Code | Inspect code...`.

Example output:

[image]

See also my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606317/561422) to a similar question.